# can't interact with firestore in my https callable cloud function

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

in my cloud code, in my HTTPS Callable function, as soon as I try to interact with firestore, everything seems to stop working. My function in my index.js file:

```
exports.paymentInfoGiven = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
console.log(data);
console.log(context);

(async function() {
    // Create a Customer:
    const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
        source: data.tokenId,
        email: data.email,
    });
    admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(data.userId).update(
        {customerId: customer.id, givenPaymentInfo: true}
    ).then( 
        data => {
            console.log('it worked: ' + data);
        } // this logged 5 minutes after the above console.logs
    ).catch(
        err => {
            console.log('it didnt work1: ' + err);
        }
    );

    admin.firestore().collection('games').doc(data.gameId).collection('host').get()
        .then(
            hostCol => {
                hostCol.forEach(
                    host => {
                        if (data.userId === host.id) {
                            admin.firestore().collection('games').doc(data.userId)
                                .update({givenPaymentInfo: true})
                                .then(
                                    data => {
                                        console.log('worked' + data);
                                    }
                                )
                                .catch(
                                    err => {
                                        console.log('it didnt work2: ' + err);
                                    });
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        )
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('it didnt work3: ' + err);
        });
})();
});
```

The above code creates a customer on Stripe just fine. It logs the first 2 lines just fine and THAT"S IT. Doesn't log the stuff inside .then() or .catch(), i don't get any error messages (see image below), it deploys just fine when i 'firebase deploy'. Not sure what's going on.

My imports for my index.js file:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const stripe = require("stripe")("secret_key");
```

My client side code that's calling the above function:

```
import {AngularFireFunctions} from '@angular/fire/functions';
import {from, Observable, Subscription} from 'rxjs';

constructor(private fns: AngularFireFunctions) {}

uponGivingPaymentInfo(email: string, tokenId: string, userId: string, gameId: string): Observable<any> {
   const callable = this.fns.httpsCallable('paymentInfoGiven');
   return callable({tokenId: tokenId, email: email, userId: userId, gameId:gameId});
}
```

[My firestore logs after uponGivingPaymentInfo is executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CMJI.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to modify your code at different levels: return to the client after all the asynchronous tasks are done, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#sending_back_the_result, chain the different promises returned by the asynchronous calls, and finally you may use a batched write for updating the docs. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes. I would suggest you watch the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/

Comment: thanks. Learned about promises and used promise.all to fix the issue and took out the async await in the stripe function, just made it a regular function